# npm start server errors

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to start my npm server ( yes I have deleted the `nodes_module` folder and `package-lock.json` file ) and npm installed in that same location numerous times. I have also tried `ng update @angular/cli`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I am getting the following errors now

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:44:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:31:21)
    at BuildCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:201:32)
    at BuildCommand.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:53:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:3:12)
    at BuildCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:52:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shawn Rahmani\Documents\GitHub\Community-Solar-Enrollment-Flow\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:127:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Comment: Has this worked before?
Can you checkout an older revision and see if that runs?

Comment: yep its worked before - I can give that a try

Comment: @SRahmani May be this will help you https://filipmolcik.com/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found/?

Comment: @SRahmani Just make sure the global version of and local version  of angular cli are matching

Comment: @JameelM i probably should have clarified I am only trying to run locally - so should that matter?

Comment: @SRahmani Ideally no. when you create a new angular cli project it uses global. but it's better to keep in sync to avoid any unusual behavior with the tool

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this command ? npm cache clean -f

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either your not in the same directory or you've recently upgraded node.

Instead of doing an `npm upgrade` you can do an `ng update`

Check here for more info

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update

You should also check if you have an `angular-cli.json` file, which was renamed to `angular.json` for newer releases.